# In which source does Imam Mahdi say "Kitab Al-Kafi is enough for our Shia"?

Tags: source-identification, shiism

Bismillahir Rahmanir Rahim. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin. Was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Sayyidina wa Azimina, Wa Habibi Qulubina wa Shafii Nufusina, Abul Qasim Muhammad. Wa 'ala Ahli Bayti tayyibina tahireen.

---

According to a Shia scholar Imam Mahdi, before he went into Ghaiba, had said "Kitab Al-Kafi is enough for our Shia". I heard it from a video in YouTube without the source being mentioned.

So the question is, **In which source does Imam Mahdi say "Kitab Al-Kafi is enough for our Shia"?**

Answer (score 0):

However, it is a well-known quote among some Shiites that the book of "Al-Kafi" has been presented to the last Imam of the Shiites and he has said that "Al-Kafi" is enough for our Shiites.
But this story is not cited in scientific forums. Because this word was not uttered by the author of the book Usul Kafi (Sheikh Klini) and none of his students, and its narrator is not specifically mentioned anywhere, but some scholars of the book "Al-Kafi" have narrated this statement in their introduction. For example, in the introduction of "Al-Kafi", the publication of "[Dar al-Kitab al-Islamiyya](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BNwf.png)" states that:
[و یعتقد بعض العلماء أنّه عرض على القائم - صلوات اللّه علیه - فاستحسنه و قال: کاف لشیعتنا.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXF67.png)
And some scholars believe that it was presented to the Qaim - may God’s prayers be upon him - so he approved of it and said:(Al-Kafi) is sufficient for our Shiites.
(You see that the narrator is still unknown ...)

The most similar sentence that I found this phrase in Islamic books is in the book "Ma'ani al-Akhbar" Which is related to the interpretation of verse "کهیعص" "Kãf-Ha-Ya-’Aĩn- Ṣãd.
[کَافٌ کَافٍ لِشِیعَتِنَا](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVMsi.png)
"Kãf" (the first letter of the first verse of Surah Maryam in Quran) enough for our Shiites

Comment: Please, format the the Arabic texts you quoted properly, and kindly give the English translation of the texts, as I do not understand Arabic. Neither do many other users at this site I believe.

Comment: English translation added.